# Django can't resolve url path 404

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, httprequest

Hi I'm having a very annoying issue with django:
I've setup many urls paths and they all work fine except one and I really can't figure out why:

**Urls**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # path('foods/search', food_search),
    path('food_list/',
         FoodListVersionListCreateAPIView.as_view(),
         name='foodList-list'),
    path('all_foods/<str:survey>/<str:string>',
         FoodListCreateAPIView.as_view(),
         name='food-list'),
    path('food_classification/',
         FoodClassificationListCreateAPIView.as_view(),
         name='foodClassification-list'),
    path('food/<str:survey>/<str:string>/',
         FoodDetailAPIView.as_view(),
         name='food-detail'),
]
```

**Views**

```py
class FoodListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Food.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FoodSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['description', 'food_code',
                        'cofid_code', 'foodex_code',
                        'food_classification']
    search_fields = ['food_list', 'SYSTEM_TIME']
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        assert self.queryset is not None, (
            "'%s' should either include a `queryset` attribute, "
            "or override the `get_queryset()` method."
            % self.__class__.__name__
        )

        survey = self.request.query_params['survey']
        food = self.request.query_params['string']
        raw_queryset = perform_food_search(survey, food)
        queryset = Food.objects.filter(pk__in=[i.pk for i in raw_queryset])

        if isinstance(queryset, QuerySet):
            # Ensure queryset is re-evaluated on each request.
            queryset = queryset.all()
        return queryset
```

**Error message**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?survey=…&string=…` is the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), this is *not* part of the path. You thus can not capture these with `path(…)`. The path thus looks like:

```
path('all_foods/', FoodListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='food-list'),
```

you then thus retrieve the parameters with:

```
survey = self.request.query_params['survey']
food = self.request.query_params['string']
```

It is however *not* guaranteed that the `survey` or `string` keys are in the querystring, you thus should check this with:

```
if 'survey' in request.query_params and 'string' in request.query_params:
    # …
else:
    # …
```